# Apache Spark does not delete temporary directories

Tags: apache-spark

After a spark program completes, there are 3 temporary directories remain in the temp directory.
The directory names are like this: spark-2e389487-40cc-4a82-a5c7-353c0feefbb7

The directories are empty.

And when the Spark program runs on Windows, a snappy DLL file also remains in the temp directory.
The file name is like this: snappy-1.0.4.1-6e117df4-97b6-4d69-bf9d-71c4a627940c-snappyjava

They are created every time the Spark program runs. So the number of files and directories keeps growing.

How can let them be deleted?

Spark version is 1.3.1 with Hadoop 2.6.

**UPDATE**

I've traced the spark source code.

The module methods that create the 3 'temp' directories are as follows:

- DiskBlockManager.createLocalDirs
- HttpFileServer.initialize
- SparkEnv.sparkFilesDir

They (eventually) call Utils.getOrCreateLocalRootDirs and then Utils.createDirectory, which intentionally does NOT mark the directory for automatic deletion.

The comment of createDirectory method says: "The directory is guaranteed to be
newly created, and is not marked for automatic deletion."

I don't know why they are not marked. Is this really intentional?

Answer (score 33):

Three `SPARK_WORKER_OPTS` exists to support the worker application folder cleanup, *copied here for further reference*: from [Spark Doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts)

- `spark.worker.cleanup.enabled`, default value is `false`, Enable periodic cleanup of worker / application directories. Note that this only affects standalone mode, as YARN works differently. Only the directories of stopped applications are cleaned up.
- `spark.worker.cleanup.interval`, default is 1800, i.e. 30 minutes, Controls the interval, in seconds, at which the worker cleans up old application work dirs on the local machine.
- `spark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl`, default is 7*24*3600 (7 days), The number of seconds to retain application work directories on each worker. This is a Time To Live and should depend on the amount of available disk space you have. Application logs and jars are downloaded to each application work dir. Over time, the work dirs can quickly fill up disk space, especially if you run jobs very frequently.

Comment: Thanks, but it's only for Spark standalone mode. The 'temp' directory is created for local mode and YARN-client mode.

Answer (score 21):

I assume you are using the "local" mode only for testing purposes. I solved this issue by creating a custom temp folder before running a test and then I delete it manually (in my case I use local mode in JUnit so the temp folder is deleted automatically).

You can change the path to the temp folder for Spark by `spark.local.dir` property.

```java
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local")
                                .setAppName("test")
                                .set("spark.local.dir", "/tmp/spark-temp");
```

After the test is completed I would delete the `/tmp/spark-temp` folder manually.

Comment: Thanks, it's a possible workaround. BTW, I've filed a JIRA for this issue. Please see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7439 .

Comment: Thanks you saved the day

Comment: Is there a way it can automatically delete those files?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to make Spark cleanup those temporary directories, but I was able to prevent the creation of the snappy-XXX files. This can be done in two ways:

1. Disable compression. Properties: spark.broadcast.compress, spark.shuffle.compress, spark.shuffle.spill.compress. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/configuration.html#compression-and-serialization
2. Use LZF as a compression codec. Spark uses native libraries for Snappy and lz4. And because of the way JNI works, Spark has to unpack these libraries before using them. LZF seems to be implemented natively in Java.

I'm doing this during development, but for production it is probably better to use compression and have a script to clean up the temp directories.

Comment: Although I've not tested, it may be possible to set a system property org.xerial.snappy.lib.path so that snappy module look for the snappy DLL rather than unconditionally extract the DLL. See the comment of the source file https://github.com/rvs/snappy-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/xerial/snappy/SnappyLoader.java

Comment: But according to https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java/issues/46 , It may have already been resolved. Maybe Spark has older library?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call close() on the spark context that you created at the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think cleanup is supported for all scenarios. I would suggest to write a simple windows scheduler to clean up nightly.

Answer (score 0):

for `spark.local.dir`, it will only move spark temp files, but the snappy-xxx file will still exists in /tmp dir. 
Though didn't find way to make spark automatically clear it, but you can set JAVA option:

```
JVM_EXTRA_OPTS=" -Dorg.xerial.snappy.tempdir=~/some-other-tmp-dir"
```

to make it move to another dir, as most system has small /tmp size.