# Spark cleanup job not running

Tags: apache-spark, datastax

Whenever I do a `dse spark-submit <jarname>`,it copies the jar in `SPARK_WORKER_DIR` (in my case /var/lib/spark-worker/worker-0). I want to get the jar automatically deleted once the spark job is successfully completed/run.  Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30100967/2879445), I changed my `SPARK_WORKER_OPTS` in `spark-env.sh` as follows :

```
 export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="$SPARK_WORKER_OPTS -Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.interval=1800"
```

But the jar is still not getting deleted. Am I doing something wrong? What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Adding this line to spark-env.sh and restarting the dse service worked for me:

```
export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="$SPARK_WORKER_OPTS -Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.interval=3600 -Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=172800 "
```

I restarted the dse service by

```
nodetool drain
sudo service dse restart
```

This deletes the log 2 days after the job is complete.